# ¿Cómo puedo exportar la información extraída de la API de Finca Raíz a un archivo CSV?

Tags: csv, scraping

Soy nuevo explorando el tema de Web scraping (con Python), me he apoyado en esta importante red para desarrollar el código, pero cuando trato de exportarlo a CSV (Stack Ovf 3) me guarda a una información diferente a la que imprime en el terminal de PyCharm (Stack Ovf 1). Quiero extraer los apartamentos que se venden en Cali del portal de fincaraiz.com.co

Esta es la URL de la API: https://api.fincaraiz.com.co/document/api/1.0/listing/search
La URL de donde extraigo la información: https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/apartamentos/venta/cali

Lo que me exporta en CSV:
[image: No me arroja la información de los apartamentos, solo los títulos]

Lo que visualizo en la terminal de PyCharm

[image: En esta si se aprecia la información de los apartamentos]

Esta es una imagen de la consola de chrome donde se aprecia la carga útil de la API.
[image: Donde saco la información para los diccionarios]

Agradezco mucho su ayuda al respecto.
Este es el código que estoy trabajando.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
   "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
    Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36",
   "referer": "https://fincaraiz.com.co/"
}

 json_data = {
 'filter': {
    'offer': {
        'slug': [
            'sell',
          ],
      },
    'property_type': {
        'slug': [
            'apartment',
          ],
      },
    'locations': {
        'location_point':[
            [
             -76.59027692154969,
            3.535311581094419
            ],
            [
            -76.48934003190125,
            3.3689308955117525
            ],
        ],
    },

 },

 'fields': {
    'exclude': [],

    'include': [
        'area',
        'baths.id',
        'baths.name',
        'client.client_type',
        'client.company_name',
        'client.first_name',
        'client.last_name',
        'garages.name',
        'is_new',
        'locations.cities.name',
        'locations.cities.slug',
        'locations.countries.name',
        'locations.countries.slug',
        'locations.groups.name',
        'locations.groups.slug',
        'locations.groups.subgroups.name',
        'locations.groups.subgroups.slug',
        'locations.location_point',
        'locations.neighbourhoods.name',
        'locations.neighbourhoods.slug',
        'locations.states.name',
        'locations.states.slug',
        'locations.view_map.slug',
        'media.floor_plans.count',
        'media.photos.list.id',
        'media.photos.list.image.full_size',
        'media.photos.list.is_main',
        'media.videos.count',
        'min_area',
        'min_price',
        'price',
        'products.configuration.tag_name',
        'products.label',
        'products.name',
        'products.slug',
        'property_id',
        'fr_property_id',
        'rooms.name',
        'title',
        'property_type.name',
        'offer.name',
        'fr_parent_property_id',
    ],
    'limit': 100,
    'offset': 100, #set to 25 to get the second page, 50 for the 3rd page etc.
    'ordering': [],
    'platform': 40,
    'with_algorithm': False,
   },
}

response = requests.post('https://api.fincaraiz.com.co/document/api/1.0/listing/search', 
headers=headers, json=json_data)
data = response.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)

print (df)

df.to_csv("aptos_fr_cali")
```

Answer (score 0):

pudiste lograr el tema? no se nada pero me gustaria saber si puedes desarrollar algo similar para Medellín con varios portales, como servicio. me escribes

Saludos,

Camilo Murillo
3175031196

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que pusiste en el dataFrame de pandas el request **json_data**, cuando debias poner el response

Antes

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
```

Despues

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Aunque evitando crear una variable yo pondria directo el **response.json()**

**PD:** antes de guadar el archivo csv tendrias que realizar limpieza de datos para que sea un archivo legible.